# Convert string to DateTime em LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq, datetime

Tenho uma *model* onde todos os campos são `string`.

Quero converter para `DateTime` e `Double`

Para isso criei uma nova *model*

```
public class CPUStats
{
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public Double? Disco { get; set; }
    public Double? CPU { get; set; }
    public Double? RAM { get; set; }
}
```

e fiz esse select:

```
  var DateQuery = db.servidorSQL.ToList().Select(o => new CPUStats
            {
                Data = DateTime.Parse(o.Data),
                CPU = Double.Parse(o.CPU),
                RAM = Double.Parse(o.RAM),
                Disco = Double.Parse(o.Disco)
            });
```

Porém obtenho o erro:

> **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

na linha: *`var DateQuery = db.servidorIIS.ToList().Select(o => new CPUStats`*

Faço essa conversão porque depois eu faço uma consulta por ordem de data:

```
 var CPU = DateQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Data).Take(5).ToList();
```

*No MSSQL esse campo data que é `string` está com os seguintes dados:*
03/16/2016 04:09:16.936

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiro, só deveria usar um `Parse()` se tem certeza que o formato não pode falhar. Caso contrário precisa usar um [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads), o que exigiria um método auxiliar se quiser usar no LINQ.

Se pode garantir que o formato seja este, pode usar a cultura ou personalizar o formato esperado para o *parser*.

Me parece que a cultura resolverá:

```
DateTime.Parse(o.Data, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Se não resolver, tente o [`ParseExact()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(o.Data, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SBhUHr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tu4hHo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ParseExact3.cs).

Talvez seja melhor ainda usar um [`TryParseExact()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__).

Ou pode precisar de alguma variação disto. Veja mais [formatos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: então eu fiz certo, o que faltou foi especificar o formato da data que o linq não está entendendo? o padrão en-US não deveria ser default?

Comment: O LINQ não tem nada a ver com isso. Mas faltou o formato. O *default* depende do computador onde está sendo executado.

Answer (score 4):

> Devo ressaltar que a forma demonstrada pelo @Maniero é a mais indicada. Irei apenas mostrar que existem outras formas.

Uma forma simples é utilizando o [Convert.ToDateTime.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) Essa forma irá fazer a conversão do valor. Porém, caso o valor não seja uma data válida, irá dar erro.

Um exemplo seria:

```
var stringData =  "06/20/2016";

var stringDataConvertida = Convert.ToDateTime(stringData);

Console.WriteLine(stringDataConvertida);
```

[Veja o exemplo funcional no dotNetfiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oE8cVT)

Comment: O problema é que convert.TodateTime no Linq não dá certo.

Comment: @Dorathoto Funcionar funciona, basta olhar o exemplo. Porém, como eu disse, se passar uma data que ele não aceita, irá dar erro. Por isso disse também que a outra resposta é a melhor. Apenas postei uma outra forma de fazer, pois meios nunca é demais.