# Validação de data e hora

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, validação

Como eu faço para que no campo data, não seja salvo uma data que já passou,por exemplo a de ontem e no campo hora não seja digitado uma hora inválida, por exemplo 27:00, somente as horas brasileiras. Ambos os campos são `MaskedTextBox`.

Validação da Data:

```
public static bool ValidaData(string maskdata)
        {
            DateTime resultado = DateTime.MinValue; 
            if (DateTime.TryParse("dd/MM/yyyy", out resultado))    
            return true; 
            return false;
```

Verificação da data:

```
if (clnValidacoes.ValidaData(maskdata.Text) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inválida!");
                maskdata.Focus();
            }
```

Mas toda data que eu coloco dá "Inválida". Na validação da hora:

```
public static bool ValidaHora(string maskhora)
        {
            String hora = "";
            String[] hms = hora.split(":");
            int horas = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]);
            int segundos = Integer.parseInt(hms[2]);
            int minutos = Integer.parseInt(hms[1]);
            if (horas > 24)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fica dando erro no Interger.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Estes códigos são aleatórios e não safem sentido. Qual é sua dificuldade? O que deseja resultar? Dê detalhes para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Eu tenho uma classe de Validação com os códigos, Ok? Dentro da codificação do botão salvar, eu coloquei um outro código que vai verificar(através da classe de Validação) se os dados inseridos são válidos. Eu gostaria que me ajudassem com esse código, pois não sei se está certo. Na validação de data, o usuário não pode colocar uma data que já passou(Exemplo:a de ontem) e a de hora não pode colocar uma hora diferente a do nosso horário brasileiro(exemplo:25:00).

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O código postado na pergunta não faz sentido. Na verdade ele não compila, tem partes que sequer é C#. A pergunta também não deixa muito claro qual é o resultado esperado, mas fiz o que pude para ajudar.

Primeiro retirei redundâncias. Seria interessante aprender como as linguagens realmente funcionam, todos operadores existentes, etc. Assim fica mais fácil fazer o certo e simplificar códigos.

Se deseja pegar uma data que sabe que está sempre certa (vem de um controle que entra a data em formato definido), [não precisa usar o `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Para pegar uma data em formato específico o ideal é usar o [`ParseExact()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118450/101). Tenho minhas dúvidas se precisa disto ou se esse é o formato adequado, mas reproduzi o que está na pergunta.

Para pegar o dia de ontem tem que pegar o dia de hoje menos um. Tenho minhas dúvidas se é isso que precisa. Esta é uma implementação ingênua de como fazer isto. Pode ser que precise analisar mais alguma coisa.

Se a hora estiver vindo de um controle próprio, a hora deve estar ok, mas se não for o caso, talvez o `Split()` já não funcione. Teria que fazer um *parser*. Como não sei bem qual era a intenção reproduzi o que estava no código mas usando C#. Tenho dúvidas se esta verificação é adequada.

```
public static void Main() {
    if (!ValidaData("24/10/2016")) WriteLine("invalido");
    if (!ValidaHora("27:10:15")) WriteLine("invalido");
}
public static bool ValidaData(string maskdata) => DateTime.ParseExact(maskdata, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
public static bool ValidaHora(string maskhora) => int.Parse(maskhora.Split(':')[0]) <= 24;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ScFizV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lvqzdr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Validation.cs).

Comment: Não deu certo. Mas valeu pela atenção e paciência, ainda estou aprendendo a programar.

Comment: O código do @bigown dá certo sim se for do jeito que você necessita,o input da inválido caso o horário do dia ser por exemplo 27:00.E também na questão de horas funciona.Ou você necessita em tempo real de que o código não passe,e ao usuário digitar não deixe passar o input ? Mesmo assim a verificação teria que ser feita através de outros meios e não em tempo real.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, pelo que entendi vc tem dois problemas:

1. Vc precisa garantir que aquilo é uma data
2. Essa data tem que ser maior que a data atual

O melhor é trabalhar com a data e hora junta e verificar se elas juntam compõem uma data valida, e depois verificar se a data é menor que a atual:

```
        public static bool ValidaDataHora(string data, string hora)
        {
            DateTimeFormatInfo brDtfi = new CultureInfo("pt-BR", false).DateTimeFormat;
            try
            {
                DateTime dataehora = Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0} {1}", data, hora), brDtfi);
                if(dataehora < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```